# JMeter pressure sometimes can not stop the thread

Tags: performance, jmeter

After setting the duration of JMeter, sometimes several threads will fail to stop. No requests will be found, and no errors will be reported. The interface service will not stop the last few threads even after the JMeter is shut down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're violating probably the most important [JMeter Best Practice](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html):

**GUI mode is only for tests development and debugging**, when it comes to test execution you should be running it in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)  and this is what JMeter says each time you launch it:

[image]

If you still want to know the reason of thread getting stuck - take a thread dump (if you can use the GUI still):

[image]

and inspect what this thread is doing and where/by what it's blocked. If you cannot use GUI the thread dump can be taken by [command-line tools](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump)

More information on JMeter tuning for maximum performance: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)